# How to transfer iMessages to the computer for archival?

Tags: iphone, messages, data-transfer

My iPhone storage space is almost all used up, mostly because of my messages. I don't want to just delete all my conversations.

Is there a way I can transfer my messages onto my PC?

Comment: I would love to find out the same thing! I am selling my iPod and I have a MacBook, and I have over 100 contacts and messages and need to save them on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a PDF archive of your messages on your iOS device using [**PhoneView**](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/):

[image]

> Export messages as beautiful PDF files. PhoneView also automatically backs up your messages whenever your iPhone is connected.